# Running elasticsearch in docker

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I'm trying to run elasticsearch in a Docker container on my laptop (Mac OS) and running my tests connecting on the TCP port 9300.

First I tried to run it without docker:

```
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-5.1.1.zip
unzip elasticsearch-5.1.1.zip
cd elasticsearch-5.1.1

echo "cluster.name: test
client.transport.sniff: false
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

network.host:
- _local_
- _site_

network.publish_host: _local_" > config/elasticsearch.yml

./bin/elasticsearch
```

All works well.

Now if I try in docker:

```
docker run -p 9300:9300 -ti openjdk
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-5.1.1.zip
unzip elasticsearch-5.1.1.zip
cd elasticsearch-5.1.1

echo "cluster.name: test
client.transport.sniff: false
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

network.host:
- _local_
- _site_

network.publish_host: _local_" > config/elasticsearch.yml

chmod 777 -R .
useradd elastic
su elastic
./bin/elasticsearch
```

It would work for the first suite of tests but not the second one where it throws:

```
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes were available: [{nlR3i79}{nlR3i797RuKXJqS86GExXQ}{O6ltC6a5R-asNMuvCt3c4w}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
```

Cheers

Comment: Is that elasticsearch version compatible with the Java version in openjdk?

Comment: have you tried the [`elasticsearch`](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/) image?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look here:

- https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

Here an example:

```
docker run -d elasticsearch:5.1.1
```

Comment: Running elasticsearch via the docker images on dockerhub works really well, just be careful about the persistence of your storage. i.e. if you load it up with loads of data and then delete the container all your data will be gone.

Comment: Yes, it is highly recommended  to start the container with
`-v "$PWD/esdata":/usr/share/elasticsearch/data` to have persistent data